# Don't suggest java completion when edit clojure file with Vim

Tags: vim, clojure

I want to suggest java Omni completion when edit clojure file with Vim. I've tried slime.vim and vimclojure plugin, but they don't suggest it. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [latest version of Slimv](https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv) does java method name completion on pressing `<Tab>`. Please note that completion is a swank function, so you need to have `swank-clojure` installed and running, and Slimv must be connected to it. You start and connect the swank server in Slimv by pressing `,c` . The easiest way to install `swank-clojure` is via Leiningen, make sure that you have the `lein swank` command available.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with java completion? VimClojure suggest names of imported classes. At the moment it does not provide method names or arbitrary classnames. This is planned for a future release.

When you have typed the classname/method name already somewhere in an open buffer the normal vim completion (<C-n>) will suggest those.